# how can i simplify this logical circuit (A'C+'A'B'C) + 'B'C

Tags: logic, simplicial-stuff

### _____|A|______|/C|_____
             ____|                                                        |___
            |           |___|/A|__|/B|__|/C|_____|     |
    ___|                                                                           |____
            |                                                                            |
            |_______|/B|_______|/C|________|

Comment: 'A'B'C+'B'C can be reduced to...

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified as follows:

\begin{array}{l}
& AC' + A'B'C + B'C' & \text{ Given }\\
& AC' + A'B' + B'C' & \text{ Consensus 1 }\\
& AC' + A'B' & \text{ Consensus 2 }\\
\end{array}

There's two different rules that I've seen called "Consensus".

**Proof of "Consensus 1":**

\begin{array}{l}
& ABC + A'B & \text{ Given }\\
& (ABC + A')(ABC + B) & \text{ Distributive }\\
& (BC + A')(ABC + B) & \text{ Reduction }\\
& (BC + A')(AC + 1)B & \text{ Distributive }\\
& (BC + A')1B & \text{ Identity }\\
& BC + A'B & \text{ Distributive }\\
\end{array}

**Proof of "Consensus 2":**

\begin{array}{l}
& AB + A'C + BC & \text{ Given }\\
& AB + A'C + BC1 & \text{ Identity }\\
& AB + A'C + BC(A + A') & \text{ Identity }\\
& AB + A'C + ABC + A'BC & \text{ Distributive }\\
& AB(1 + C) + A'C(1 + B) & \text{ Distributive }\\
& AB1 + A'C'1 & \text{ Identity }\\
& AB + A'C' & \text{ Identity }\\
\end{array}

Comment: the circuit was like this (A'C+'A'B'C) + 'B'C
@Pé de Leão

Comment: obrigado @Pé de Leão